# rsync: polling for new files

Tags: background, daemon, rsync, polling

I've got:

`$ rsync -azv zope@myserver:/smb/Data/*/*/*    ~/rsynced_samples/`

And I want it to run forever, syncing any new file as soon as it appears on myserver:

(specifying a poll interval, such as 4 seconds would be an ok comprise)

Comment: If "one minute" was an ok compromise, you could just use cron.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rsync you can use inotifywait which use kernel specific file changes triggers.

This script (inotify.sh) can you give an idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$1

inotifywait -q -m --format '%f' -e modify -e move -e create -e delete ${directory} | while read line

do
    echo "doing something with: $line";

    # for example:
    # cp $line to <somewhere>
```

You can invoke this script specifying the "monitor" directory, in this way

```
./inotify.sh ~/Desktop/
```

The *$line* variable contains the full file path.

If you want to limit to only newly created files you can use on the flag "*-e create*"

Answer (score 0):

Use cron to set up a check based on your time interval (say, every minute, perhaps?) . This link should help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Note that a cron tab is set up on your machine side, not in your bash script

also useful: http://benr75.com/pages/using_crontab_mac_os_x_unix_linux

and here is a code example:

1) crontab -e // this opens up your current crontab or creates one if it does not exist
2) enter:     * * * * * file.sh >> log.txt  // this would pipe the output of your file to a log file and run it every minute.

hope that helps

Comment: Running rsync every minute will cause a noticeable impact on performance when dealing with 10k+ files. and with 100k+ you may run into problems where cron is starting a new rsync before the last one finished.